# How to mock modules python, patch does not find the attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-mock

In a function I'm using uuid1 that I want to patch.

```
def myFunction():
     my_value = uuid4.int
     smth else..
```

I want to be able to mock my_value so it always returns the same number in my unit test, because I need it for further use.
I tried doing:

```
 @patch('folder.myFunction.uuid4')
 def test_myFunction(self, mock_value):
      mock_value.return_value = 22222
```

But it throws an error saying myFunction does not have uuid4 as an attribute.

How do I mock its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is correct. Your function does not have a `uuid4` attribute.

I'm reading between the lines assuming [`uuid4` is a method of the `uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) module that normally generates a random uuid.

When testing you said you want it to always return the same value. To do that you can substitute a [`unittest.mock.Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) for `uuid.uuid4`.

```
In [36]: uuid_mock = Mock(return_value=uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b9f3e'))

In [37]: uuid_mock()
Out[37]: UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b9f3e')
```

Something like this for testing the following function (`f`)

```
import uuid, unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

def f():
    z = uuid.uuid4()
    return z.int
```

The target for the patch is the `uuid` method - `uuid.uuid4`. Specify a `unittest.mock.Mock` with a fixed return value for the `new` parameter of *the patch*. During the test, the Mock will be substituted for `uuid.uuid4`

```
class TestF(unittest.TestCase):

    uuid_mock = Mock(return_value=uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b9f3e'))

    good_uuid = uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b9f3e').int
    bad_uuid = uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b5a31').int

    @patch(target='uuid.uuid4', new=TestF.uuid_mock)
    def test_myFunction_True(self):
        self.assertEqual(f(), self.good_uuid)

    @patch(target='uuid.uuid4', new=TestF.uuid_mock)
    def test_myFunction_False(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(f(), self.bad_uuid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Result:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

---

If you want to test a function that relies on `f`'s return value and you want `f` to always return the same value during testing then make `f` the target for *the patch*.

```
def g():
    return f() == uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b9f3e').int

class TestG(unittest.TestCase):
    good_uuid_mock = Mock(return_value=uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b9f3e').int)
    bad_uuid_mock = Mock(return_value=uuid.UUID('77f1df52-4b43-11e9-910f-b8ca3a9b5a31').int)

    @patch(target='__main__.f', new=TestG.good_uuid_mock)
    def test_myFunction_True(self):
        self.assertTrue(g())
    @patch(target='__main__.f', new=TestG.bad_uuid_mock)
    def test_myFunction_False(self):
        self.assertFalse(g())
```

Comment: Tank you, but I get the error that I mentioned. myFunction does not have uuid4 as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your import. Let's say you have a module called `module.py`, and you have an import like this:

```
from uuid import uuid4
```

This means that in this module we now have a variable called `uuid4`. This is the thing to mock.

```
@patch('path.to.module.uuid4.int')
```

Comment: I tried but then I'd get path.to.module is not a package.

Comment: Can you show your import statement then? Obviously, path.to.module is not literal, you should set your own path there.

Comment: Yes, I have the path to the method there.
@patch('utilities.user_data.myFunction.uuid1.int'), and the error says: 
No module named utilities.user_data.myFunction'.
utilities.user_data is not a package.

Comment: A module is the Pythonic language for a file. Is the file that your function is in called `myFunction`? If so, what is your directory structure?